# Plot individual data points in each group after pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to group a dataframe using several criteria and then visualize individual data points in each group using a scattered plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df_tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
df_tips.groupby(['sex', 'day', 'smoker'])['tip']    # How could I scatter plot individual tip in each group?
```

Ideally, I'd like to have something looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simpler way to do this and the plot is more beautiful (I think).

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df_tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
df_tips['Groups'] = df_tips[['sex', 'day', 'smoker']].astype(str).agg('.'.join, axis=1)
sns.swarmplot(x='Groups', y='tip', data=df_tips)
plt.xticks(
    rotation=90, 
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='x-large'  
)
```

**Here is the output:**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
df_tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
groups = df_tips.groupby(['sex', 'day', 'smoker'])['tip']

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for  i,(k,v) in enumerate(groups):
    ax.scatter([i]*len(v), v)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(groups)))
ax.set_xticklabels([k for k,v in groups],rotation=90);
```

Output:

[image]